# volley request being hit twice to the server

Tags: android, android-volley

I have experienced a problem with volley where a request sometimes gets hit twice to the server and as a result, this pretty much messes up my code logic. Is there a way I can limit the number of requests to 1? I have tried doing what is explained [here](http://www.techstricks.com/avoid-multiple-requests-when-using-volley/) but the problem still occurs sometimes

Comment: try to paste the code here so that it can be easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just thought I could answer this, i figured out the solution. Google finally adopted the volley library and this is the official repo to add to your dependencies 
`compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'`

Also, add this to your string request. Set the `DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS` multiple times, like in my case, i set it to 5

```
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 5, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```